# SwiftUI: Hiding Text with an if statement if text value is nil or N/A

Tags: ios, swift, text, swiftui, hide

I am trying to do something that was simple to me in UIKit - but cannot get working in SwiftUI.

I am pulling data from an API. That data is dynamic - some parts of the call may not be present every time. I have protected the app by making all of that data optional and using a nil operator to return "N/A" in the text fields where there is no data. In UIKit I was able to simple use an if statement:

```
if self.cityLabel.text == "N/A" {
    self.cityLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Now in SwiftUI, I have the following:

```
HStack() {

     Text(self.model?.city ?? "N/A")
                            
}
```

When the data is present, it displays without any issue. However, I am not sure where to access this property or put an if statement because this data is in a View class and does not accept functions.

So basically, how do I hide that text and have the blocks around it "move up" (like display: none) in HTML while in SwiftUI? How can I implement if statements in the View code?

I'm sure it's probably simple, but assistance would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: If `city` is nil, do you want to display "N/A", or nothing at all?

Comment: nothing at all!

Comment: Ok, see if my answer works

Comment: See comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if`, `if-let`, and `if-else` now also work inside `View` (I think it's introduced in Xcode 12). This should work:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        if let city = self.model?.city {
            Text(city)
        }                      
    }
}
```

Edit: If you don't care about what's inside `self.model?.city`, just do a simple boolean test for nil.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        if self.model?.city != nil {
            /// self.model?.city is not nil!
            Text("Not nil")
        }                  
    }
}
```

Edit 2: Ok, so if the text is "N/A", you don't want to display it. However, because the text itself (`self.model?.city`) is an optional, you need to unwrap it first.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack() {
        if let city = self.model?.city { /// unwrap self.model?.city
            if city != "N/A" { /// city is not "N/A"!
                
                /// show the text
                Text(city)
            } /// else, don't show anything
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: It's telling me: ```Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer```

Comment: I am looking for this condition: ```if let self.model?.city != "N/A" { display text }```

Comment: Oh, just remove the `let`. You use `if let` when you want to unwrap an optional (`self.model?.city` is an optional) and get its value. But if you don't care about what's inside `self.model?.city`, just use `if`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear - the text will show "N/A" if there is no value. I need an if that checks for "N/A" in the text, and if it's there, does not display that text block.

Comment: The code works now, thank you! One last question: how can I make the area that the label took up no longer push other items on the view down? They are not showing any more but the data below did not move up - there is just a gap. Any ideas?

Comment: `if` should automatically remove the gap while hiding the view. It could be that currently you're just showing/hiding the label, but the `HStack` is there no matter what. Is the `HStack` embedded in another `HStack` or `VStack`?

Comment: It's embedded in more stacks haha

Comment: Oh alright then, does an `if` on the stack itself work in removing the gap?